# iPhone app store, how to release preview app just for customer

Tags: iphone, app-store, release, app-store-connect

I know you can release your app throw iTunes connect and use the 50 redoom code for customer to free download.

But is there a preview store I can use to allow customer have a preview before I actually release to the app store?

Cheers
Phil

Comment: No there isnt...out lives would have been much easier if this option existed. especially when dealing with PR firms, etc.

Comment: You can use ad hoc distribution and send your app directly to your customers (or let them download it from your server) for test purposes.

Comment: Just get the UDID of the device you want to install the app , add that UDID in the provisioning portal , regenerate the profile and install it. Rebuild the app and send your customer the provisioning profile and the .app file. They will have to copy that in iTunes and then sync that to their device. Or use ad-hoc profiles. There is no preview store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

testflight is the option !!!!

I can be read at :[testflight's official site](https://www.testflightapp.com/)